# mysql_query return non null array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wamp

I'm executing the following query:

```
    if (isset ($_POST['valider']) ){
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            $login=$_POST['login'];


  $sql ='SELECT * FROM artisant WHERE pseudo="'.$login.'" AND password="'.$password.'"';
  echo $sql;


            $req = mysql_query ($sql) or die ('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
            $nbr = count($req);
            echo $nbr;
            if(empty($req)){
            echo " <p>Incorrecte user name or password ! </p> ";
            }
            else {
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
            $_SESSION['num']=$req['num'];
            $_SESSION['prenom']=$req['prenom'];
                        $_SESSION['nom']=$req['nom'];
                        $_SESSION['mail']=$req['mail'];
            $_SESSION['nbr_ventes']=$req['nbr_ventes'];
            $_SESSION['CA']=$req['CA'];
            }

            mysql_close();

            }


}
```

and the login and password I'm passing to the query are incorrect ( they don't exist in the data base) however the returned result is a non empty array ( the size of req after the query is 1) and due to this it enters to the while loop where it is not supposed to enter unless a corresponding login and password is found.

Thank you for your help

Comment: make an echo of $sql and see the query to understand if login and password are passing well

Comment: Since it's non-empty, is it returning an existing row, or just jibberish?

Comment: there is no row to return with the specified login and password !

Comment: the password and login are well passed I just re checked

Comment: What exactly is returned? How do you check that you have a result?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Nothing having the table format is returned !

Comment: @TarikMokafih Please edit your question, show us the code you use to check for a result and an example of the output you get. You are not showing us the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$req` is a resource, not the rows.

`$nbr = count($req);` makes no sense, use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead:

```
$nbr = mysql_num_rows($req);
if ($nbr == 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you Mathieu it's perfect